# DSolve with coefficients and assumptions

Tags: differential-equations, assumptions

The command below:

```
DSolve[{s'[t] == l t, s[0] == 0}, {s[t]}, {t, 0, a}]
```

gives the error

> `DSolve::alliv`:
>   The function `s[t]` was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables.

I am trying to make `l` a constant coefficient. How do I get around this problem? I also want to be able to add the following:

```
Assumptions -> {l > 0, a > 0}
```

Edit: Removing `a` causes the error to no longer appear but I want `a` to be there. The following seems to work:

```
wrap_l = l
wrap_a = a
DSolve[{s'[t] == wrap_l t, s[0] == 0}, {s[t]}, {t, 0, wrap_a}]
```

Is there a cleaner solution? The command I want to achieve is

```
DSolve[{s'[t] == -λ s[t] p[t], p'[t] == μ s[t] p[t], s[0] == s0, p[0] == p0}, {s[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}, Assumptions -> {λ > 0, μ > 0, s0 > 0, p0 > 0, tMax > 0}]
```

Comment: Why not just `DSolve[{s'[t] == l t, s[0] == 0}, s[t], t]`?

Comment: @J.M. 1. There needs to be some restriction on `t` 2. That does not work when there are multiple coefficients

Comment: "There needs to be some restriction on `t`" - then put it in the assumptions: `DSolve[{s'[t] == l t, s[0] == 0}, s[t], t, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < t < a, l > 0}]`.

Comment: For your more complex example, the version without initial conditions works: `DSolve[{s'[t] == -a s[t] p[t], p'[t] == b s[t] p[t]}, {s[t], p[t]}, t]`; you should be able to work backwards from there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[s];

eqns = {s'[t] == l t, s[0] == 0};
```

The solution does not vary with `a`

```
Table[DSolve[eqns, s, {t, 0, a}][[1]], {a, Range[5, 50, 5]}] // Union

(*  {{s -> Function[{t}, (l t^2)/2]}}  *)
```

So just use

```
soln = DSolve[eqns, s, t][[1]]

(*  {s -> Function[{t}, (l t^2)/2]}  *)

eqns /. soln

(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Consequently,

```
s[t_] = l t^2/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the warning `DSolve::alliv` is an evidence of bug, you may contact WRI. As a workaround, just use the old syntax

```
DSolve[{s'[t] == -λ s[t] p[t], p'[t] == μ s[t] p[t], s[0] == s0, 
  p[0] == p0}, {s[t], p[t]}, t]
```

`DSolve` warns it used inverse function, but it's not a big deal. If you still feel worried, let's solve it in another way. First obtain the general solution:

```
generalsol = 
 First@DSolve[{s'[t] == -λ s[t] p[t], p'[t] == μ s[t] p[t]}, {s, p}, t]
```

Plug it back into the boundary condition and solve for the constants:

```
assumption = {λ > 0, μ > 0, s0 > 0, p0 > 0};

constant = First@
  Solve[Simplify[Reduce[{s[0] == s0, p[0] == p0} /. generalsol, {C[1], C[2]}], 
    assumption], {C[1], C[2]}]
```

The combination of `Solve`, `Simplify`, `Reduce` is a result of trial and error, you can also use

```
constant = First@
  Simplify[Solve[{Sequence @@ assumption, s[0] == s0, p[0] == p0} /. generalsol, {C[1], 
     C[2]}], assumption]
```

which also works but a little slower.

Finally plug the sonstant back into the general solution:

```
Simplify[{s[t], p[t]} /. generalsol /. constant, C[3] ∈ Integers]
(* {(s0 (p0 λ + s0 μ))/(
 E^(t (p0 λ + s0 μ)) p0 λ + s0 μ), (
 E^(t (p0 λ + s0 μ)) p0 (p0 λ + s0 μ))/(
 E^(t (p0 λ + s0 μ)) p0 λ + s0 μ)} *)
```

It's the same as what we got with the one line solution above.